# JSON.stringify() replacer function and namespace

Tags: javascript, json, namespaces

I am trying to highlight some part of a JSON in Javascript, found in the following const `namespace` using JS JSON.strigify() second parameter `replacer`. So when the key is equal to the namespace, it increase the index in the namespace to progress. Finally, I am surrounding the value with keys 0 and Z.

```
const dataTree = {
    "styles": {
        "elements": {
            "heading": {
                "typography": {
                    "fontFamily": "Volkorn",
                    "fontSize": "16px"
                },
            },
        },
        "typography": {
            "fontFamily": "Vollkorn",
            "fontSize": "16px",
            "lineHeight": "1.7"
        }
    }
}

const namespace = "styles.typography.fontSize".split('.')
let i = 0

const replacer = (k, v) => {
    if(namespace[i] === k){
        i++
        if(i === namespace.length-1){
            if(Object.keys(v).includes(namespace.at(-1))){
                v[0] = 'before' 
                v["Z"] = 'after' 
                return v
            }
        }
    }
    if(v["Z"]) {
        delete v["Z"]
        delete v[0]
    } 
    return v
}
const strV = JSON.stringify(dataTree, replacer, 2)
```

The problem is not following the right path. In the above example, it goes to `styles.elements.heading.typography.fontSize` instead of `styles.typography.fontSize`.

Any idea ?

Comment: You've said you want to do this in "a JSON," but what you've shown is a JavaScript object. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. Are you trying to do this in a JavaScript object that you'll then serialize to JSON? Because it's hard (maybe impossible) to do this with a replacer function, but fairly easy to do it before the conversion to JSON.

Comment: Please also show the *result* you expect.

Comment: The `dataTree` is a JS object, yes. The `strV` is the JSON string version, including some special keys to surround the values I would like to hightlight.

Comment: I was expecting the stringify method to have more precise control over the replacer function which only provide a key and value but no path or namespace to identify precisely the part of the object that is being treated. 
If you run it, you get the result similar to what I expect. Problem is that is modifies `styles.elements.heading.typography.fontSize` instead of `styles.typography.fontSize`.
Finally, I am going to make that changes to do it before the conversion to JSON, as there is no opportunity to check the path the replacer function is at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a replacer, it is called recursively on the modified object that the replacer returns.

If the replacer is inserting new properties into the tree, this makes it difficult to keep track of the position in the tree that the current invocation of the replacer is working on.

You can do this with objects instead:

```js
const dataTree = {"styles":{"elements":{"heading":{"typography":{"fontFamily":"Volkorn","fontSize":"16px"}}},"typography":{"fontFamily":"Vollkorn","fontSize":"16px","lineHeight":"1.7"}}};

const namespace = 'styles.typography.fontSize'.split('.');

const replaceAtLocation = (tree, [p,...rest], replacer) => rest.length ?
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(tree).map(([k,v])=>k===p ?
    [k,replaceAtLocation(v, rest, replacer)] : [k,v])) : replacer(tree);

const result = replaceAtLocation(dataTree,namespace,tree=>Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(tree).flatMap(([k,v])=>k===[...namespace].pop()?
    [['A','before'],[k,v],['Z','after']]:[[k,v]])));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Note that I've replaced '0' with 'A', since '0' would be always be ordered as the first property in the object, rather than immediately preceding the desired property.

Comment: Well, your answer is totally working. Still it is very compact, it will take some time for me to understand it all. 
Thank you!